# Check checkbox by clicking other button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to check a checkbox by clicking the button next to it.

```
<p class="label">NSFW?: </p><br />
<p>
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="nsfw" /> 
    <span id="nsfwbtn" class="btn btn-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Not Safe For Work (18+)" > 
        This image is not safe for work. 
    </span>
</p>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PGCYX/

Answer (score 3):

This is what `<label />` was invented for, you don't need JS at all.

```
<p>
  <input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="nsfw" /> 
  <label for="cb" id="nsfwbtn" class="btn btn-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Not Safe For Work      (18+)" > 
    This image is not safe for work. 
  </label>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PGCYX/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a bit of JavaScript/jQuery to create an OnClick event for the image and when you onclick an image/button you'll need to set the value/check state of checkbox to 'true'

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.

```
$('#nsfwbtn').click(function(){
     if(!$('#cb').is(":checked")){
         $('#cb').prop("checked",true);
     }
     else{
         $('#cb').prop("checked",false);
     }
});
```